# Which Node &NPM version is compatible with sitecore 10.3.1

Tags: sitecore-react

we are upgrading the sitecore from 9.3 to 10.3.1 but we are facing issue from Node side, Could anyone help us and shared the information  which Node &NPM version is compatible with sitecore 10.3.1

Answer (score 0):

What I found on various documentation is to run NVM install @. For the Sitecore XM Cloud 10.3, node `v18.13.0` is preferred.

So during your installation or upgrade, first install Node Version Manager. You will use this to install any version of Node for your projects.

Download Node Version Manager [here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases/download/1.1.10/nvm-setup.zip).

After downloading the .zip file, open the file from your Downloads folder as an administrator and follow the instructions.

For more reference follow this link.

https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/set-up-a-development-environment-for-sitecore-xm-cloud-10

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Always good to spin up the new JSS app with JSS template which will help you to find the latest supported version or check the XM Cloud Head app

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/latest/sitecore-headless-development/create-a-jss-project-for-the-latest-versions-of-jss-and-sitecore.html

https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head